# react-native-scratch-card (Android Only) is giving "Device: (35:287) Invariant Violation"

Tags: react-native

i have used "react-native-scratch-card (Android Only)" in my React native App. I have got this error after run my application.

```
Device: (35:287) Invariant Violation: View config not found for name RNScratchCardManager.

This error is located at:
    in RNScratchCardManager
    in t
    in RCTView
    in Login
    in r
    in t
    in RCTView
    in RCTView
    in RCTView
    in u
    in C
    in t
    in n
    in RCTView
    in n
    in RCTView
    in t
    in n
    in RCTView
    in t
    in t
    in u
    in s
    in r
    in t
    in P
    in Routes
    in RCTView
    in App
    in RCTView
    in RCTView
    in n
    in n
    in v
    in RCTView
    in RCTView
    in c
```

i can't find any error in the files. Is there any thing to do for solve this? I think this is related to device. But i want to know the error. Please anyone can help me will be great and please let me understand what is wrong here. Thanks in advance.